# how to dd /dev/sdX to /dev/mmcblkX?

Tags: linux, debian, dd, mmc, block-device

I made a Debian 10 system image in virtual machine and written it to external HDD. I wanted to copy the system to a laptop's disk, but it has SSD disk that shows up as /dev/mmcblk.
My system has 3 partitions **sda1, sda2, sda5**. Target disk has 4 - **mmcblk0p1-4**. There are also two disks - **mmcblk0boot0 and mmcblk0boot1**.
What should I worry about when dd'ing /dev/sda to /dev/mmcblk0? Can i just do `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/mmcblk0`? Should I write bootloader elsewhere? I tried to look for an answer online but I haven't been able to find an answer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go ahead and just try it and everything (kind of) worked fine. I just needed to fix some wrong block counts via **fsck** and then booted successfully.
Here's what I did:

1. did `dd if=/dev/sda bs=1M status=progress of=/dev/mmcblk0`
2. The input device was way bigger than SSD, so I waited until it died with 'No more free space'
3. rebooted
4. After boot, I was told that **/dev/mmcblk0p1 requires manual fsck**
5. I ran `fsck /dev/mmcblk0p1` from **initramfs**
6. It asked to recover journal, answered yes.
7. Was told that free block count is wrong and if I wanted to fix it. Answered yes.
8. Was told that inode count is wrong and if I wanted to fix it. Answered yes.
9. Rebooted
10. Booted successfully

Comment: Please add more detail, e.g. the exact options you used.

Comment: I added details about my solution.